# What does the [x,y] symbol mean in a multidimensional array access?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm studying C and I came across the code below. The printed results are always the same for all the `printf` calls.

What does `[x,y]` mean? 
A memory address or something else?

```
printf("%d ", array[0,0]);
printf("%d ", array[1,0]);
printf("%d ", array[2,0]);
```

Comment: Two words: comma operator.  Many words: the subscript expression contains a comma operator which evaluates the LHS (0 or 1 or 2) and discards that, then evaluates the RHS (always 0) and that is used as the subscript into the array, so you always get the same value printed — `array[0]`.  And if `array` is actually a 2D array of some sort, then `array[0]` will be an address rather than a simple integer value.  A good compiler would generate several warnings per line — find the options to convert your compiler into a good compiler, or get  good compiler.

Comment: The comma operator discards the result of the left side. `array[0,0]` is the same as `array[0]`.

Comment: Three words: don't do that.

Comment: I imagine your compiler gives you warning about this if you use them as you should. With `gcc`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, though there might be better choices.

Answer (score 11):

The [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in [c](/questions/tagged/c) returns the second argument. So `0,0`, `1,0`, and `2,0` all evaluate to `0`, so its no wonder that all the `printf` statements print the same result. If you want to refer to an element in a two-dimensional array by its indexes, you need to use two sets of square bracket. E.g., `array[1][0]`.

Comment: Also, most compilers will warn about the discarded expression if asked for warnings.

Answer (score 7):

It's  a 'comma operator'. In C, a comma operator evaluates each argument but returns the ***rightmost argument***. So `array[0,1]` is as same as `array[1]` and `array[0,1,2]`is as same as `array[2]`. In your case `array[0,0])`, `array[1,0]`, `array[2,0]` all evaluate `array[0]`. So all the statements print the same result.

**Additionally** (*from @chqrlie's comment*), though it returns the *rightmost argument*, all the expressions are evaluated so any side effects are performed: `printf("%d ", array[exit(1),0]);` will not print anything.

Comment: You might add a note about all expressions getting evaluated so any side effects are performed: `printf("%d ", array[exit(1),0]);` will not print anything :)

Comment: This is a important point @chqrlie . Thanks for adding this point.